# Get value of custom field in category admin

Tags: categories

I am using [cfs-custom-category-fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/cfs-custom-category-fields/faq/) plugin.

In their documentation it says that to get the value of a custom field in category you should use `CfsTaxonomy::get('field_name')`

This works well when I am in a category page, like `category-24.php`.

But it doesn't work in `index.php`.

How do I get the value in a non-category page? I tried something like this:

```
$cat_id = 29;
    if($cat_id=29){
        echo CfsTaxonomy::get('arata_in_listare');
    }?>
```

But it doesn't work.

I suppose I need to create a category page-like environment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this function: [`get_post_custom_values`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values)

The first parameter is the name of the key, `arata_in_listare`, and the second the post id, depending on where are you making the call you might not need to pass it.

In this community we don't give support for plugins, so I'm showing you the "wordpress" way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't do it, I finally created one manually in functions.php